How do I lower the similarity index percentage in iThenticate?
I have run into a situation where a "plagiarism detection software" (I believe the one being used is called iThenticate) is showing 31 % similarity index for my document. In the list at the end of the report, it shows 20 entries under "Primary sources" (all have a subtitle "Internet" which I think is supposed to say all the matches with my document were found in other documents on the Internet) where the similarity percentages for each entry ranges from 6%, 1240 words to 1%, 118 words. This document is in the Humanities field. How should my document be modified to reduce this similarity index?

I have some sections in this document that have been paraphrased from another article (literally copy/pasted), but they have all been cited in the reference section. Are these one of the triggers for the similarity? The report shows some paraphrased material as being similar to something else (understandable) but not others. Should the paraphrased sections be formatted in some way to have the software ignore it?

Some common words such as "Chapter", "Introduction", etc and few common phrases are flagged as being similar to something else (words such as "chatper", "also" are flagged on one page, but not flagged in another). How concerned should I be about these? If I need the similarity index to be below some threshold percentage how do I ensure words like these do not take me above the threshold?

Some sections of the document are my own words, but the phrasings used are common enough that the entire section is being flagged as being from someplace else. How should I modify sections such as these?



Why do you want to reduce this metric? Presumably anyone sane looking at it will be able to see that the detector is just detecting a lot of regular things and not plagiarism.

Are you running the software yourself, or is someone else running it and just giving you the output?

"paraphrased from another article (literally copy/pasted)" -- That doesn't really make sense. To be clear, you copy-pasted and then changed some words, or do you mean something else?

@DanielR.Collins may be paraphrased wasn't the right word. Its a copy/paste of a statement from another article, something like, According to Smith, ".....". This has also been listed in the references for the document. Nothing from another article has been listed as if they were my own words.

@JoshuaZ it's one of the requirements for the document to get accepted, similarity index percentage needs to be below certain threshold

@Anonymous a department at the University will run it through the software and give me the results. I think its one of those softwares where a single document check costs $130 or something for a normal person, so not really feasible for an individual. The software gives out a pdf file where sections it detects as similar to something else are highlighted in colour, and at the end of the document there is a list of colours and the associated source which my text is similar to. For eg if I copied a paragraph from wikipedia, it would be highlighted in blue and in the list at the end, ...

... it will show that the blue sections came from wikipedia .com

@user13267: That would of course be a "quote", not a "paraphrase" (I'm assuming you've actually got the copied text noted in quotation marks). It's, respectfully, kind of a red flag to not know that.

Is the goal of this rule to detect/prevent plagiarism, or is there some other purpose that you know of? As the answer states, for plagiarism this makes no sense, so are you able to make some other sense of it?

And is this mandatory?  If it is, whoever is mandating it should have guidelines on how they set the software up (and I've used it-- it definitely has settings) and what you should do with or about the results.

@Anonymous yes this is mandatory and after some looking around there seems to be guidelines (exclude quotes/bibliographies/phrases/small matches-10 words/source matches-by 1%), so now I don't understand how it's counting words like "Introduction" as a match. One issue I can think of is may be all the phrases cited from other articles are not properly formatted (not within quotation marks for example), but I'd assume such instances would be clearly highlighted in the report, as I'm guessing those are the easiest problems for the software to catch

@Snijderfrey This is apparently to prevent plagiarism. I'm not aware of anything else this is possibly being mandated for

@user13267 It sounds like the people running your institution are extremely foolish if they base things on this software output. Completely worthless education they're subjecting you to, I'm afraid.

Ignore it. You've identified bad software.
Similarity is not plagiarism. It can be a clue that plagiarism has happened, but you do not need to "reduce similarity". Be certain you have not plagiarized, and then be happy with this and stop sending content you haven't plagiarized to a similarity detector; these tools are for people who don't know whether the content they are reading is plagiarized or not.
Some better things to focus on:

I have some sections in this document that have been paraphrased from another article (literally copy/pasted)

This does not make sense. If something is paraphrased, it is not literally copy/pasted. If it's literally copy/pasted, quote it and be clear that it's literally copy/pasted, and then do not worry about similarity. Generally this is best done sparingly; if you find yourself needing to quote long passages frequently without special reason (like critiquing a specific passage in a work of literature) then there is something wrong with your overall approach to the writing project rather than a problem of similarity: you're regurgitating something that already exists rather than creating something new. Take a couple steps back and reevaluate your goals. You may not need to include this at all and just direct your reader to the source if they need further information.
If you've copy/pasted and then just edited a few words or changed the grammar/phrasing to try to make it less "similarity index", you've just plagiarized. Making more of these trivial edits will not make it less plagiarized even if you make it less "similarity index". Either mentally digest the content and completely rewrite it from scratch from your own head while citing individual pieces of fact necessary to support your argument, or go back and verbatim quote the whole thing with quotation marks and a clear citation that it came from someone else's writing.

If I need the similarity index to be below some threshold percentage

If this is a rule by someone at your institution, I am sorry to inform you that either this person is an idiot or your entire institution is a joke. You cannot solve this problem by changing your similarity index, you're still attending an incompetent institution if this is how they treat plagiarism. Just think about it: if you were actually able to make your work "not plagiarized" by doing things like using some other word instead of "chapter" or "introduction", what is the purpose of this? There is no purpose. Absolutely asinine rule with no educational value. How can you possibly trust someone who imposes rules like this that have no value, when they are clearly showing how little they understand academia and writing and the meaning of the output of the software they are using? You'll have to decide how to handle that information, though.

"Ignore it, you've identified bad software" -- why? I agree with the rest of your answer, but according to the body of the question there are 20(!) instances that have been flagged, each ranging from ~100(!!) to over 1000(!!!) words. In this case I think the software is doing exactly what it was designed to do...

I must in good conscience downvote this, because per the OP's comments, its use is mandated.  Ignoring it seems unwise.

@hiccups The similarity score is not actually what's telling OP they've copied something, though. If they've copied without quoting, that's the problem, not the similarity. If they've copied without quoting but then edited enough to trick the similarity score, that's still equally a problem. Worse, the similarity score may encourage this obfuscation behavior that resolves similarity while preserving plagiarism. So, the similarity score provides no additional information that the author doesn't already have about how they wrote their paper. That's why they should not use a similarity score.

It's hard to be sure, but it seems like the software is mis-configured.
If your institution's guidelines are, from your comment:

exclude quotes/bibliographies/phrases/small matches-10 words/source matches-by 1%

And it is still reporting those, then either someone is not setting up the exclusion criteria correctly, or you can ignore that part of the report.  You still have other issues to work through.
But, as much as I hate the expression, this is a classic XY Problem.
You are asking X:  How can I lower this score?
You should ask Y:  What are the guidelines for using this tool, how does it work, and what do I need to do with or about the result?
And you need to ask your professor, or advisor, or editor, or whoever is mandating the use of this tool for this paper.
Because we can't tell you.
(As an example, for my dissertation, I was told how to set up the software to run it myself, and then had to write a brief justification for each of the software's squawks.  Presumably someone read it-- I never heard another word about it.  I have no expectation that your process will be the same.)

Hi thanks for the response. The paper has been edited enough that the index is now within the required thresholds. I am curious about one thing though (and since you said you have setup the software yourself, I hope this is appropriate to ask), during the second run through the software, a section in the document that wasn't marked as plagiarized, is marked as plagiarized now, when nothing in that section was changed. Is this normal behaviour for this software? If the same document is passed through the software multiple times, is it normal for the software to mark different sections...

...of the document at different times, or does it mark the same sections as copied from the same source every time? There was about a week and a half time difference between the first and second pass of my document. Can this make any difference, or does it indicate that some settings have been definitely changed during the first and the second pass? In my case I only get a similarity report at the end of the pass (a pdf file that just says "certain %age" of "certain section" has been found similar to "certain site", and I don't have the option of going to the exact source where the section...

...is supposedly copied from. If you set up the software yourself do you get the feature of just clicking on a marked section and viewing the exact source where the section has been supposedly copied from?


How should my document be modified to reduce this similarity index?

Don't plagiarise.
From one of your comments, "quotes/bibliographies/phrases/small matches-10 words/source matches-by 1%" can be ignored. So any matches for singular words ("introduction", "chapter" etc.) as well as "common phrases" (each of which should be maybe ~10 words long?) can be ignored---sensibly so.
The bigger problem is where you have "20 entries... where the similarity percentages for each entry ranges from 6%, 1240 words to 1%, 118 words". Check each of these entries. Have you copied/pasted from those sources as suggested by the software? If yes, you have plagiarised. If no, follow the advice in Brian's answer.
